# Is there a way to specify an Object in a dynamicField in Apache Solr 4.6.1

Tags: apache, solr

I have just started to work on Apache Solr and this might be a rookie question.

I understand that dynamicField for primitives can be configured in schema.xml, but is there a way to specify a user defined datatype (i.e. an object), in the schema.xml?
I was unable to find this in the [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields).

Comment: What are you thinking about when you're mentioning an "object" datatype? I'm not familiar with such a thing in Solr. Dymamic fields are like any other field, they're just wildcard matched when finding the definition in the schema.

Comment: @MatLindh : I'm thinking of an object which has several attributes (POJO), as opposed to a primitive datatype.

Comment: There is such thing in Solr. The libraries accepting the POJO (such as SolrJ) converts it to a Solr document with each field being a primitive datatype. Solr has no concept of "Objects". It does have parent/child documents and blockjoins, but you'll usually keep Solr more performant and easier to use if you avoid them.

Comment: ah ok, thanks @MatsLindh